# Windows second monitor sometimes stays black

Tags: windows-8, boot, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have two monitors and both of them work fine most of the time, however, occasionally when Windows 8 boots up the secondary monitor shows nothing but black during and after the bootup. In these cases it's completely unresponsive and the only way to start using it is to restart the computer. This occurs slightly less than 50% of the time and I've noticed a pattern...

I typically see three steps during bootup: it displays the motherboard's UEFI graphic, then the blue windows logo, and then the desktop. Both monitors show the UEFI graphic 100% of the time. The blue windows logo always shows up on the main monitor first and then within two seconds it shows up on the secondary. If the computer gets to the third phase BEFORE the blue logo shows on the second monitor then the second monitor stays black and unresponsive indefinitely. I have a suspicion that the SPEED of the bootup is affecting whether the second monitor works, is that possible?

The main monitor uses hdmi, the secondary is dvi. They are both connected to my radeon 7950 card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wouldn't go as far as to say that the boot up speed is affecting your graphics card, if anything its the problem with the monitors that is causing booting problems. have you tried reinstalling your graphics card drivers? this may help.

Comment: There must have been something wrong with the version of drivers I was using because I updated them and the issue hasn't appeared in a few days. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: my pleasure, glad it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking two things in this case:

1. Check if you can see the second monitor in Windows display. If it does pick up the monitor and it's enabled, then try disabling it and re-enabling it. If the monitor does come back up from this then you may have a power issue from Windows. You may need to adjust your power settings to ensure that it enables that monitor.
2. If you can't see it in Windows, check to see if it detects it in CCC. If it does, try doing the same as above inside CCC. The two programs might be fighting it out.

It most likely won't be the "speed" of the boot up. It will be a Windows setting.

As a last ditch effort, if none of the above works, try and turn down the brightness of your second monitor in its settings. Then give it a good reboot. I ran into an issue like that once and strangely enough that was the resolution.